# how to fix column position in <table> when <input> in <td> in a <tr> row are being toggled to hide/display with none/block

Tags: javascript, html, css

My number of columns in my 2x2 table expand or contract based on the value chosen in the select, 1 or 2. Currently, as the columns increase or decrease, the column position(s) on the screen shift wildly about. How can I fix the column on the screen no matter how many columns appear in a row?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  switch (x) {
    case "1":
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
          if (j == 0) {
            tds[j].style.display = "block";
          } else {
            tds[j].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    case "2":
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
          if (j < 2) {
            tds[j].style.display = "block";
          } else {
            tds[j].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Select">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<TABLE id="myTable" style="border-spacing: 25px 10px; width:75%" cellspacing="0">
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align="left">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align="left">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align="left">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align="left">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: " the column position(s) on the screen shift wildly about. " I do not see any shifting at all, perhaps you can recreate the issue in a snipit that will show inconsistencies on the parsing of the code?

Comment: not able to recreate the error with code provided. can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I used Chrome for a browser and the shifting occurs as I change the number of columns in the table. What do you mean by a snipit? How do I create one?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L1q5w4g0/ I added the code to fiddle, but can't seem to get it to work on fiddle.

Comment: well does seem to move alot

Comment: Can you attach your `css` as well? @user840930 (since this question is tagged `css`)

Comment: Do you mean that you have this type of behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/tm2ndxw5/3/ ? like the input change their places?

Comment: didn't have separate css

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior. If you add more columns, more than 2. For example, with 3, 4, 5, or 6, the columns really shift about to make more space for the columns.

Comment: CSS: `justify-content: left; align-items: left;`.
HTML: add in any `<tr>` at the end: `<td style="width:100%"></td>`.
JavaScript: instead of `switch` use code for `case "2"` and change `if (j < 2)` to `if (j < x)`.
HTML: add as many tds as you want, and add corresponding select options.
You may want to set width of select as it will expand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I needed to set the css value display:grid. This is the behavior I was looking for. With this display:grid, the columns remain fixed even as new columns are deleted or added. Thank you everyone for your input!

This css was added to the table:
display:grid

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this ?:

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
     var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var row = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            tds[j].style.display = "block";
        }
        for(var j = x; j < tds.length; j++){
          tds[j].style.display = "none";
        }
    } 
    
  }
```

```css
input{
    width: 100%;
    max-width:177px;
  }
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">    
  <option value="Select">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>

</select>

<TABLE id="myTable" style ="border-spacing: 25px 10px; width:75%" cellspacing="0">   
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column3" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column4" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column5" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column6" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column7" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column8" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column9" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column10" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column3" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column4" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column5" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column6" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column7" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column8" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
     </TD>
     <TD class="column9" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column10" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE>
```

Or do you want like that ?:

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
     var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var row = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            tds[j].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        for(var j = x; j < tds.length; j++){
          tds[j].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    } 
    
  }
```

```css
input{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 177px;
  }
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">    
    <option value="Select">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  
  </select>
  
  <TABLE id="myTable" style ="border-spacing: 25px 10px; width:75%" cellspacing="0">   
    <TR>
      <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column3" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column4" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column5" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column6" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column7" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column8" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column9" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column10" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column3" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column4" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column5" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column6" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column7" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column8" align = "left" >   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
       </TD>
       <TD class="column9" align = "left">   
        <div>
          <input value = "0"></input>
        </div>
      </TD>
      <TD class="column10" align = "left" >   
       <div>
         <input value = "0"></input>
       </div>
      </TD>
    </TR>
   </TABLE>
```

Comment: no, I think he doesn't want it to swift as mention in the question I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what (he/she) wants exactly but I guess (he/she) wanted it this.

Comment: nope if you see the comments he/she is saying that the problem is with the shifting.

Comment: I didn't see a problem with shifting and thought, what could be the problem, what could he have wanted to tell. maybe I got it right, maybe wrong. I do not know exactly that. So I am waiting for the answer of the question owner :)

Comment: When I run this code snippet here in stack overflow when it says "Run code snippet", it looks good, like what I want. The columns are relatively stable. But when I run this on my Chrome browser on my windows laptop, the columns jump about. When there is only 1 column, the column is in the middle of the screen. When 2 columns are selected, the columns split the screen. And three columns divide the screen in thirds, and so on. I want the columns to not do this.

Comment: I improved my answer again, check it please

Answer (score 0):

Well as you see there is nothing swifting when you expand or contract the columns.
So if you see any swifts could you like put a picture of the with 1 column and with 2 columns so I could see if there is a difference and then I might be able to help you.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    switch (x) {
       case "1":
          for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
              var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
              for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
                if (j==0) {
                  tds[j].style.display = "block";  
                } else { 
                  tds[j].style.display = "none";
                }  
              }  
           } 
        break;
       case "2":
           for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
              var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
              for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
                if (j<2) {
                  tds[j].style.display = "block";  
                } else { 
                  tds[j].style.display = "none";
                }  
              }  
           }
        break;
        default:       
   }
 }
```

```html
<TABLE id="myTable" style ="border-spacing: 25px 10px; width:75%" cellspacing="0">   
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
     <div>
       <input value = "0"></input>
     </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1" align = "left">   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2" align = "left" >   
      <div>
        <input value = "0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>        
  </TR>
 </TABLE>

 <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">    
   <option value="Select">Select One</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: when I run this code snippet here in stack overflow, it looks okay. But in my Chrome browser on my laptop, if I select 1 column, it shifts to the middle of the screen. If I select 2, then two columns appear splitting the screen. So, one column moves from the middle of the screen to maybe 25% of the way. I don't want this movement. I just want the column to be fixed in place with more columns added after it, with the same spacing, without the columns jumping about the screen, every time the number of columns is changed.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can acheive this with help of CSS, please find the code below and let me know if anything is missing.

Major change is added below CSS and removed the corresponding from HTML.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  switch (x) {
    case "1":
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
          if (j == 0) {
            tds[j].style.display = "block";
          } else {
            tds[j].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    case "2":
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var tds = row[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
          if (j < 2) {
            tds[j].style.display = "block";
          } else {
            tds[j].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Select">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<TABLE id="myTable" style="border-spacing: 25px 10px;" cellspacing="0">
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="column1">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
    <TD class="column2">
      <div>
        <input value="0"></input>
      </div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: ohh Right, I did not check by clicking show snippet.

Comment: even with these css changes, the columns still bounce about every time a different option is selected.